# Inverting List Elements in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to invert two-elements lists in `xs`. For example, `invert [[1,2], [5,6,7], [10,20]]` will return `[[2,1], [5,6,7], [20,10]]`. It doesn't invert `[5,6,7]` because it is a 3 element list.

So I have written this so far:

```
invert :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
invert [[]] = [[]]
```

which is just the type declaration and an empty list case. I am new to Haskell so any suggestions on how to implement this problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

First we define a function to invert one list (if it has two elements; otherwise we return the list unchanged):

```
invertOne :: [a] -> [a]
invertOne [x, y] = [y, x]
invertOne xs = xs
```

Next we apply this function to all elements of an input list:

```
invert :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
invert xs = map invertOne xs
```

(Because that's exactly what `map` does: it applies a function to all elements of a list and collects the results in another list.)

Answer (score 4):

Your inert function just operations on each element individually, so you can express it as a `map`:

```
invert xs = map go xs
  where go = ...
```

Here `go` just inverts a single list according to your rules, i.e.:

```
go [1,2] = [2,1]
go [4,5,6] = [4,5,6]
go []    = []
```

The definition of `go` is pretty straight-forward:

```
go [a,b] = [b,a]
go xs    = xs     -- go of anything else is just itself
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
solution ([a,b]:xs) = [b,a] : solution xs
solution (x:xs)     = x : solution xs
solution []         = []
```

This explicitly handles 2-element lists, leaving everything else alone.

Yes, you could do this with `map` and an auxiliary function, but for a beginner, understanding the recursion behind it all may be valuable.

Note that your 'empty list case' is *not* empty. `length [[]]` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the following solution:

```
invert :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
invert = fmap conditionallyInvert
  where
    conditionallyInvert xs
      | lengthOfTwo xs = reverse xs
      | otherwise      = xs
    lengthOfTwo (_:_:_) = True
    lengthOfTwo      _  = False
```